# $f:X \rightarrow [0,\infty]$, $A = \{x:f(x)>0\}$. If $A$ uncountable, $\sum_{x\in X}f(x) = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

This comes from Chapter 0, `Proposition 0.20`, Real Analysis, by Folland

> $f:X \rightarrow [0,\infty]$, $A = \{x:f(x)>0\}$. If $A$ uncountable, $\sum_{x\in X}f(x) = \infty$

I am confused about the proof:

> Let $A = \bigcup_1^\infty A_n$ where $A_n = \{x:f(x)>1/n\}$. If A is uncountable, then some $A_n$ must be uncountable, and $\sum_{x\in F} f(x) > \mbox{card}(F)/n$ for $F$ a finite subset of $A_n$; it follows that $\sum_{x\in X}f(x) = \infty$.

My questions are:

1. How to get "$\sum_{x\in F} f(x) > \mbox{card}(F)/n$"?
2. How to get "$\sum_{x\in X}f(x) = \infty$" based on previous result?

Note that $$\sum_{x\in X}f(x) = \sup \left\{\sum_{x\in F}f(x): F\subset X, F \text{ finite } \right\}$$

Could anyone please provide me with detailed steps? Thanks!

Comment: @Masacroso It should be $\sum_{x\in X}$ from Folland.

Comment: @Masacroso $X$ should be the domain of the function. $X$ is an arbitrary set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\in F$, then $x\in A_n$, and $f(x)>1/n$. Let $|F|=m$, and write $F=\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}$. Then
$$\sum_{x\in F}f(x)=f(x_1)+\cdots+f(x_n)\ge 1/n+\cdots +1/n=m/n.$$

If $|A_n|=\infty$, then $A_n$ has arbitrarily large finite subsets $F$,
and then
$$\sum_{x\in A_n}f(x)\ge \sum_{x\in F}f(x)\ge\frac{|F|}{n}$$
which can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: I am still a bit confused on "if $x\in F$ then $x\in A_n$". How to claim this? I still miss something..

Comment: As you wrote, "...for $F$ a finite subset of $A_n$...." @sleevechen

Comment: I get it, thanks!

Comment: @AnginaSeng, could you please explain where the fact of $A_n$ being uncountable is being used?

Answer (score 2):

Since $A = \bigcup_1^\infty A_n$ is uncountable, then there is some positive integer $n$ such that $A_n$ is infinite. 
Hence for any positive integer $m$ there is a finite set $F_m\subset A_n$ such that $\mbox{card}(F_m)>m$, and it follows
$$\sum_{x\in A_n} f(x)\geq \sum_{x\in F_m} f(x) > 
\sum_{x\in F_m} \frac{1}{n}=\frac{\mbox{card}(F_m)}{n}>\frac{m}{n}$$
which is arbitrary large. We may conclude that
$$\sum_{x\in A} f(x)\geq \sum_{x\in A_n} f(x)=+\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first part is clear: $\sum_{x\in F}f(x)>\sum_{x\in F} \frac{1}{n} = |F|/n$.